# c#: combobox keyvalue pair

Tags: c#, combobox

what i want to do is to populate the combobox from ManagementObjectSearcher query

what i want is a combobox that has a Name and PortNumber

so far my query works.

this is my current code

```
private class ComPort
    {
        public string PortNumber { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(
                "root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM WIN32_POTSMODEM");
            foreach (ManagementObject item in searcher.Get())
            {
                if (item["Status"].ToString() == "OK")
                {
                    cmbPort.Items.Add(new ComPort {PortNumber = item["AttachedTo"].ToString(), Name= item["Description"].ToString() });

                }

            }
```

but the output is `WpfApplication1.MainWindow+ComPort`

i tried

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return Convert.ToString(PortNumber);
}
```

and it worked, but how about the Name property?

if my code is like this

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return Convert.ToString(PortNumber + Name );
}
```

i need to split the port number and name.

thank you. Is there a better way to do this?